# layered UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, layer

I am using multiple UIScrollViews on-top of one another and Im using a UISegmentedControl to manage which one is active, my issue is, is that once I have set the position of a UIScrollView and gone to another, when I try and return I can only control the last selected one and the UIScrollView stays in the background. Does anyone know how to bring that UIScrollView back to the top?

Below is my code, cheers in advance!

```
- (void)layerSelected:(id)sender
{
int index = filterControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

switch (index)
{
    case 0: if (scroll == nil)
            {   
                scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
                scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
                scroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                NSInteger viewCount = 15;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) 
                {
                    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
                    UIImageView *filterViewOverlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                    [filterViewOverlay setImage:[filterManager objectAtIndex:i]];
                    [scroll addSubview:filterViewOverlay];
                    [filterViewOverlay release];
                }
                scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * viewCount, self.view.frame.size.height);
                [self.scroll setContentOffset:currentPos1];
                [self.view addSubview:scroll];
                [scroll release];
            }
            else
            {
                [self.scroll setContentOffset:currentPos1];
                scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
            }

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

if both scroll views are a subview of the main view then you need to call `[mainView bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];`

Comment: thanks, the problem I am having now is that the segmented control loads on segment 1 but does not load the scrollView. In order for me load segment 1 - I have to load segment 2 then go back to 1... any ideas?